# is it possible to use Google Cloud Dataflow output data to our local databases?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

i want to use the Google Cloud Dataflow  deal the data and then output the result to our local databases,is it possible? and how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can read [this docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io) to do a custom writer for your database, or use [embulk](https://github.com/embulk/embulk) to watch google storage and write output to google storage.